# How can I simulate USB storage device connection with qemu?

Tags: usb, qemu, emulation

I'm writing a program for controlling USB storage device connections (this is a classic subject). All it's ok with my program, but now, I want to write some tests. So in order to do that, I realized I'll need some way of simulate USB connections.

And not only the connections, I need to be able to set the device properties: capacity, format, etc...

Comment: what has the USB simulation to do with qemu?

Comment: Well... I saw into `systemd` code (http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) that they usit for tests on `udev`. I then make the conclusion that they must be using `qemu` to simulate some "hardware thigns."

Comment: How ever if you know other way for doing that, I'll thank you point me the right direction.

Comment: well, qemu/kvm is good for testing. in case of a failure you don't need to reboot. Special usb hardware needs to be forwarded to qemu/kvm with `usb_add`. I am not up to date with the latest dev, so I can't tell you.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution in [QEMU documentation](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/devices/usb.html):

> #### USB emulation
>
> QEMU can emulate a PCI UHCI, OHCI, EHCI or XHCI USB controller. You can plug virtual USB devices or real host USB devices (only works with certain host operating systems). QEMU will automatically create and connect virtual USB hubs as necessary to connect multiple USB devices. […]
>
> ##### Connecting USB devices
>
> USB devices can be connected with the `-device usb-...` command line option or the `device_add` monitor command. Available devices are:
>
> ###### `usb-storage,drive=drive_id`
>
> **Mass storage device** backed by drive_id (see the [disk images](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/images.html#disk-images) chapter in the System Emulation Users Guide). This is the classicbulk-only transport protocol used by 99% of USB sticks. This example shows it connected to an XHCI USB controller and with a drive backed by a raw format disk image:
>
> ```bash
> qemu-system [...]                                          \
>  -drive if=none,id=stick,format=raw,file=/path/to/file.img \
>  -device nec-usb-xhci,id=xhci                              \
>  -device usb-storage,bus=xhci.0,drive=stick
> ```
>
> ###### `usb-uas`
>
> **USB attached SCSI device**. This does not create a SCSI disk, so you need to explicitly create a `scsi-hd` or `scsi-cd` device on the command line, as well as using the `-drive` option to specify what those disks are backed by. One `usb-uas` device can handle multiple logical units (disks). This example creates three logical units: two disks and one cdrom drive:
>
> ```bash
> qemu-system [...]                                                \
>  -drive if=none,id=uas-disk1,format=raw,file=/path/to/file1.img  \
>  -drive if=none,id=uas-disk2,format=raw,file=/path/to/file2.img  \
>  -drive if=none,id=uas-cdrom,media=cdrom,format=raw,file=/path/to/image.iso \\
>  -device nec-usb-xhci,id=xhci                                    \
>  -device usb-uas,id=uas,bus=xhci.0                               \
>  -device scsi-hd,bus=uas.0,scsi-id=0,lun=0,drive=uas-disk1       \
>  -device scsi-hd,bus=uas.0,scsi-id=0,lun=1,drive=uas-disk2       \
>  -device scsi-cd,bus=uas.0,scsi-id=0,lun=5,drive=uas-cdrom
> ```
>
> ###### `usb-bot`
>
> **Bulk-only transport storage device**. This presents the guest with the same USB bulk-only transport protocol interface as `usb-storage`, but the QEMU command line option works like `usb-uas` and does not automatically create SCSI disks for you. `usb-bot` supports up to 16 LUNs. Unlike `usb-uas`, the LUN numbers must be continuous, i.e. for three devices you must use 0+1+2. The 0+1+5 numbering from the `usb-uas` example above won't work with `usb-bot`.
>
> ###### `usb-mtp,rootdir=dir`
>
> **Media transfer protocol device**, using dir as root of the file tree that is presented to the guest.

Other available devices are: `usb-ccid`, `usb-audio`, `usb-kbd`, `u2f-{emulated,passthru}`, `canokey`, etc.